# Cannot have two css files with same name in eclipse (liferay theme project)

Tags: eclipse, liferay, filenames

I have got really strange issue with eclipse.

When I create two css files with same name, editing first file will overwrite second...

How is it possible?

[image: Example]

Comment: See: https://www.liferay.com/documentation/liferay-portal/6.0/development/-/ai/anatomy-of-a-theme.

Answer (score 0):

Liferay's Theme build process assumes that your changes WILL ONLY be done in the _diffs folder.

Any change you do there will result in a build to be triggered. The simplified build steps are:

1. Copy your theme's parent theme (see entry in build.xml) into `/docroot/`
2. Copy everything from `/docroot/_diffs` into `/docroot/`, effectively overwriting the parent's files if applicable
3. Deploy theme to the server (if running)

So, you're assumed to never change any file that's not in `/docroot/_diffs`. Why are the other files readily accessible nevertheless? Well, sometimes you want to see them or just change a few aspects of the original ones. Having them available makes it easy to copy it e.g. from `/docroot/templates/portal_normal.vm` to `/docroot/_diffs/templates/portal_normal.vm`. (This will trigger the build process and copy the identical file back immediately).

Also, you shouldn't change any CSS file that Liferay brings with it, but add your changes to custom.css (or include more css files from there) to make your next upgrades easier. custom.css is always included last, so your changes will override the styling made earlier by Liferay's parent theme. Aleksandr M linked to more documentation in his comment.

Comment: This answer does not completely address the problem mentioned here .The main Question is how to retreive the unchanged code after changes made to the _diff folder and I think the answer is to copy it before any changes.

Comment: I'd say it does: "you're assumed to _never_ change any file that's _not_ in /docroot/_diffs". To phrase it differently: You're supposed to _only_ work in the `_diffs` folder. Period. If you have a file there, it will be copied over to the other location. If you want to retrieve the original file: Delete your version in `_diffs` and the original (from the declared parent theme) will reappear. Anyway, this 6.x build process is long outdated by now. In 2022 I'd not invest much time any more to understand the ~10y old build process but go for the current technique and Liferay version.